# Changing method return value in foreach loop not working

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, phpunit, magento2

I create my test to check data validation. Below I posted code from my phpunit ValidatorTest and Validator class. It worked fine without foreach loop.
For start I get array which can have many arrays inside. Each array has to contain two keys: 'code' and 'tax_class_id'. My problem is that on second iteration my Mock - groupSearchResultsInterfaceMock doesn't set right data. Function checkByCodeIfGroupExists gets empty array although it should get ['General']. When I change in my dataProvider their order that array with 'General' code goes as first it's giving me the expectedError. I have to change mock return Values in two functions in each iteration. I used xdebug and the taxClassRepositoryInterfaceMock is changing them in the correct way. I tried to understand why it's happening but found nothing. I also tried to change some things in setUp but nothing changed.

```
protected $existingTaxClassesId = [1, 2, 3];

protected $existingCodeGroups = ['General', 'NOT LOGGED IN'];

public function fullyValidBothDataProvider()
{
    return [
        [
            [
                ['code' => 'first_customer_group', 'tax_class_id' => 10],
                ['code' => 'General', 'tax_class_id' => 1],
            ]
        ]
    ];
}

/**
* @dataProvider fullyValidBothDataProvider
* @test
* @param array $validData
*/
public function passingValidationWhenTaxClassIdAndGroupCodeAreValidAndWhenTaxCodeExistsAndGroupCodeDoesNot(
    array $validData
) {
    foreach ($validData as $value) {
        $this->taxClassRepositoryInterfaceMock->method('get')->willReturn($value['tax_class_id']);
        $items = in_array($value['code'], $this->existingCodeGroups) ? [$value['code']] : [];
        $this->groupSearchResultsInterfaceMock->method('getItems')->willReturn($items);

        $this->assertTrue($this->validatorMock->validateData($validData));
    }
}

/**
 * Validates customer groups data
 *
 * @param array $data
 * @return bool
 * @throws GroupDataException when customer group data is incorrect
 */
public function validateData(array $data): bool
{
    $taxClassIdKey = GroupInterface::TAX_CLASS_ID;
    $groupCodeKey = GroupInterface::CODE;

    if (empty($data)) {
        throw new DataNotSetException(__('Data is empty.'));
    } else {

        foreach ($data as $group) {

            if (!isset($group[$taxClassIdKey]) || !isset($group[$groupCodeKey]) || !is_int($group[$taxClassIdKey])) {
                throw new GroupDataException(__('Invalid data format. Every group array must contain ' .
                    $taxClassIdKey . ' and integer ' . $groupCodeKey . '.'));

            } elseif ($this->checkByCodeIfGroupExists($group[$groupCodeKey])) {
                throw new CodeGroupException(__('Group code ' . $group[$groupCodeKey] . ' already exists.'));

            } elseif (!$this->checkIfTaxClassIdExists($group[$taxClassIdKey])) {
                throw new TaxClassException(__('Tax class id ' . $group[$taxClassIdKey] . ' does not exist.'));
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Return true if given group code exist
 *
 * @param string $groupCode
 * @return bool
 */
public function checkByCodeIfGroupExists(string $groupCode): bool
{
    $filter = $this->filterBuilder
        ->setField('customer_group_code')
        ->setValue($groupCode)
        ->setConditionType('eq')
        ->create();

    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilters([$filter]);
    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
    $result = $this->groupRepository->getList($searchCriteria);

    $items = $result->getItems();
    return !empty($items);
}



/**
 * Test setup
 */
public function setUp()
{
    //
    $objectFactoryMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Magento\Framework\Api\ObjectFactory')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $filterBuilderMock = $this->getMock('Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder', ['setValue'], [$objectFactoryMock],
        '');
    $this->filterBuilderMock = $filterBuilderMock;
    $this->filterBuilderMock->method('setValue')->willReturn($filterBuilderMock);

    $this->groupSearchResultsInterfaceMock = $this->getMock('Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupSearchResultsInterface');

    $this->filterGroupBuilderMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder')
        ->setMethods(['setFilters'])
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $this->filterGroupBuilderMock->method('setFilters')->willReturn($this->filterGroupBuilderMock);

    //
    $searchCriteriaInterfaceMock = $this->getMock('Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface');

    $this->searchCriteriaBuilderMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder')
        ->setMethods(['create', 'addFilters'])
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilderMock->method('addFilters')->willReturn($this->searchCriteriaBuilderMock);
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilderMock->method('create')->willReturn($searchCriteriaInterfaceMock);

    $this->groupRepositoryInterfaceMock = $this->getMock('Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface');
    $this->groupRepositoryInterfaceMock->method('getList')->willReturn($this->groupSearchResultsInterfaceMock);


    $taxClassRepositoryInterfaceMock = $this->getMock('Magento\Tax\Api\TaxClassRepositoryInterface');
    //changing its get function in each loop iteration later
    $this->taxClassRepositoryInterfaceMock = $taxClassRepositoryInterfaceMock;

    //
    $loggerMock = $this->getMock('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');

    $validatorMock = $this->getMockBuilder($this->className)
        ->setMethods(null)
        ->setConstructorArgs([
            'groupRepository' => $this->groupRepositoryInterfaceMock,
            'taxClassRepository' => $this->taxClassRepositoryInterfaceMock,
            'searchCriteriaBuilder' => $this->searchCriteriaBuilderMock,
            'filterBuilder' => $this->filterBuilderMock,
            'logger' => $loggerMock
        ])->getMock();

    $this->validatorMock = $validatorMock;
}
```

Comment: You have provided 147 lines of code, you are probably receiving no feedback because no one wants to vertically and horizontally scroll through all 5,321 characters of your code.  Are you able to reduce your supplied code down to something more visibly appealing while retaining the relevant components?  (I tried staring at it for a while and just got lost in it)